# hive partition name with special character

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hue

I am having issues creating a partitioned table in Hive that contains the ":" and "/" special characters as values in the partition column name.  I found this JIRA The partitions themselves get created, but I cannot access their data files on HDFS from Hue, nor can I see their results in the partition viewer in Hue.  I found a related [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1317), but the issue was fixed and committed in version 0.6.0 (I'm on 0.13)

Here is what my raw data looks like:

1241241;Joe Schmo;TAXI DRIVER;08/06/2015;01/04/2014;13:20

My temporary staging table is created like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nyc_cab_drivers
        (
            License_Number bigint,
            Name string,
            Type string,
            Expiration_Date string,
            Last_Updated_Date string,
            Last_Updated_Time string
        )
        ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        STORED AS TEXTFILE
        LOCATION '...'
        TBLPROPERTIES (
            'skip.header.line.count'='1'
        );
```

My partitioned table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS part2_nyc_cab_drivers
        (
            License_Number bigint,
            Name string,
            Type string,
            Expiration_Date string,
            Last_Updated_Date string
        ) 
        PARTITIONED BY (Last_Updated_Time string)
        CLUSTERED BY (Name) INTO 128 BUCKETS
        ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Then I load the data into the partitioned table as follows:

```
FROM nyc_cab_drivers ncd 
     INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE part2_nyc_cab_drivers 
     PARTITION (Last_Updated_Time) 
     SELECT ncd.License_Number, ncd.Name, ncd.Type, ncd.Expiration_Date, ncd.Last_Updated_Date, ncd.Last_Updated_Time;
```

For this example, I have used dynamic partitioning but the same issue happens when I use static partitioning as well (i.e. Last_UpdatedTime="12:41").  After running the load, the partitions show up in HUE.  I can see the partition columns, and the special characters are escaped by hex like this: "12%3A41".  When I click on the partition value, it opens up the partition but says "The operation has no results." under results.  When I click on the path, Hue tells me:

```
Cannot access: /user/hive/warehouse/default.db/part2_nyc_cab_drivers/last_updated_time=12:41.
IllegalArgumentException: Pathname /user/hive/warehouse/default.db/part2_nyc_cab_drivers/last_updated_time=12:41 from /user/hive/warehouse/default.db/part2_nyc_cab_drivers/last_updated_time=12:41 is not a valid DFS filename. (error 400)
```

I see the directory created in HDFS for each partition, I just can't open it to view the datafiles.  When I do a show partitions query, I see the partitions listed which means they were created, just something to do with the HDFS names.  This same issue happens when I change the partition column to the date values that have "/" characters - the only difference is I can open the partition directory and view their data files but it still shows no results for the partition.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This sounds like https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-2280

Comment: Thank you Romain for clarifying this is solely an issue with HUE.  I can confirm that the partitions were created in HDFS (from terminal in namenode, datafiles are there).